# CREATE works in this statement, but MERGE does't. What's going on here?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying this statement.

```sql
CREATE (n:TestEntity), (m1:RelatedEntity)
WITH n,m1
MERGE (m2:RelatedEntity {b:"c"})
WITH n,m1,m2
MERGE (n)-[:REL]->(m1), (n)-[:REL]->(m2)
SET n+={a:1}, m1+={b:"d"}, m2+={d:2}
return n, m1,m2;
```

This gives an error:
[image]

If I change the last `MERGE` with `CREATE`, this exact statement works.

If I remove the second relationship and only `MERGE` the first one, it works. What's going on? Is this a bug?

Comment: FYI you should edit your question to include formatted text of your error, not an image of it. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. I also formatted your Cypher query for readability. That said: It would be helpful to show more detail (such as the exact queries that did work).

Comment: @DavidMakogon tried that but couldn't get the `^` marker to get to the right position. So had to post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

At this time in Neo4j 4.2.x, MERGE does not support comma-separated patterns, though there is a feature request in the backlog to add that capability.

Answer (score 0):

MERGE does not support comma separation. A workaround is to add the `MERGE` keyword in front of every node/relation etc.

The below query works:

```
CREATE (n:TestEntity), (m1:RelatedEntity)
WITH n,m1
MERGE (m2:RelatedEntity {b:"c"})
WITH n,m1,m2
MERGE (n)-[:REL]->(m1) MERGE (n)-[:REL]->(m2)
SET n+={a:1}, m1+={b:"d"}, m2+={d:2}
return n, m1,m2;
```